# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, reactjs, http, axios, http-status-code-400

I am trying to create a client and upload an image in Form React Component, when I send it to the backend using Axios I get the message "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 400 (Bad Request)". If I create a client using postman, It creates it but when I do it in my React App, I get the 400 message. Does someone know what to do?

Comment: Post the relevant front-end/back-end code here so we can actually see what is happening.

Comment: What payload are you passing into axios data ?

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO!, while asking a questions here do share code and some of the attempts you have done to solve our issue. And also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!